# Windows 2008 R2 DHCP Overlapping Scopes

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, subnet

We are trying to troubleshoot a scope overlap problem. We have multiple device types we wish to give all different ranges of a 16 bit subnet. IE. X device we wish to give 192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254/16, Y devices we wish to give 192.168.3.1-192.168.3.254/16. We are trying to accomplish this by creating different scopes and using the 60 class identifier. The problem is DHCP won't allow us to give these scopes with 16 bit masks because of the potential overlap. We aren't overlapping the address pool so why does DHCP care and can we work around this?

If this isn't possible, how can i assign specific ranges by device type without creating multiple scopes?

Any thoughts would be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

Entire Scope is 192.168.0.0/16
Gateway is 192.168.1.1/16
Device Hardware A - 192.168.20.1-192.168.20.254/16
Device Hardware B - 192.168.26.1-192.168.26.254/16
Device Hardware C - 192.168.85.1-192.168.85.254/16

We tried to setup multiple scopes for each device type (A,B,C) but couldn't specify a 16 bit mask as Scope A could technically overlap Scope B even thought our start and end addresses don't.

I hope this makes more sense.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: The statements "We are trying to accomplish this by creating different scopes and using the 60 class identifier" AND "how can i assign specific ranges by device type without creating multiple scopes?" contradict each other. Can you clarify?

Comment: Our end goal is to give out address ranges per device type and use a 16 bit mask so they all can communicate with each other and reach there gateway.

Comment: The whole thing seems very confusing. Your address range X and Y doesn't make much sense. A 16-bit sub net in your case would range between 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 which is 65534 possible hosts. Do you want to seperate X and Y devices into two subnets or what? How many hosts are there in your net?

Answer (score 1):

Because windows counts the "scope" as 192.168.0.0/16.  Without a router of some sort, you are basically creating a huge singular subnet.

I think what you are actually trying to create is what windows calls an "address pools".  You can create one for each group, but unless you do static reservations, windows will simply assign the next available address to each device as it requests an IP.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar situation, here's what we did:

We created the scopes with a /23 mask (had to re-address a couple smaller scopes to avoid conflicts) like so:

Scope 1: 192.168.10.0/23 "vendor class identifier=A"
Scope 2: 192.168.20.0/23 "vendor class identifier=B"
Scope 3: 192.168.26.0/23 "vendor class identifier=C"
etc.

When the DHCP Server hands out the address, the device ends up with a /16 netmask. I can't honestly tell you why, but it is the desired outcome and I've got too many other things to do to reverse search it at this time.

Comment: It ends up with the mask of the server that received the request via broadcast or helper.

Comment: In the future, you should consider remapping by mask bit patterns. Don't get me wrong this will work, but you will leave yourself the most future address flexibility and avoid future expansion weirdness by setting your boundaries on power of 2 iterations of addresses. Right now if you were to expand these to a /22 your 192.168.10.* range would end up in the middle of the 8-11 range. 192.168.20.* would be ok, and 192.168.30.* would be at the end of 28-31. It isn't like you need to worry about getting to 65000-ish hosts.